# Whats the best practice for the contents of an activities onCreate method?

Tags: java, android, standards, oncreate

I'm fairly new to Android development and I've realised that my activities onCreate methods are growing significantly.

For example I can be setting up the navigation drawer, initialising the activities buttons, textviews and ads, setting up ad requests and setting all the button click listeners.

So my question is, is it considered acceptable to have an onCreate method that's 50+ lines long? Or should I separate all the individual actions (usually only 4 or 5 lines each) into individual methods?

(I was always previously taught to keep methods as short as possible only performing one thing, though the examples and tutorials I've seen all say to throw stuff into the onCreate method)

Answer (score 1):

What i do is create methods and call them in OnCreate() as you need 
For eg A Method setUpViews() for setting up all your xml views in java and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to follow "SINGLE RESPONSIBILITY PRINCIPLE", which is correct. Your class should do only one thing and it should have only one reason to change.
Same holds true for methods. If your method has more than one responsibility then it will be difficult to Unit Test your code and most importantly it will not be understandable.

What you can do is, have small methods like

1. initView - FindViewby ID codes [You can also consider using libraries like Butterknife for the same purpose]
2. initClickListeners (setclicklisteners, touchlisteners)

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

In java you need to follow Java Design Patterns in order to maintain code reusability and readability.

For Example you can extend your Activity with an Parent Activity in which you can define the application common events, such as handling Action bar clicks, Handling Back Button clicks, Handling Common Navigation Bar clicks etc.

Follow this link for understanding various types of Design Patterns:-
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/